# Joining some strings in a list of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

So, say I have a list of strings, representing lines in a file, like so:

```
Pillsy`testLines =
 {"foo",
  "bar\\",
  "baz\\",
  "quux",
  "wongle\\ bongle",
  "wingle",
  "pringle\\",
  "prongle",
  "blort"};
```

These use the (common?) convention that if a line ends with a backslash, it should be appended to the following line, giving a result like this:

```
Pillsy`testResult =
  {"foo", "barbazquux", "wongle\\ bongle", "wingle", "pringleprongle", "blort"};
```

Now, the naïve way to accomplish this is to use pattern matching, but the performance is likely to be really awful if you've got a lot of lines:

```
Pillsy`naiveCatenateContinuedLines[lines : {___String}] :=
 lines //.
  {before___, line1_, line2_, after___} /;
    StringMatchQ[line1, ___ ~~ "\\" ~~ EndOfString] :>
   {before, StringDrop[line1, -1] <> line2, after};
```

You've got two potential performance hits, one with repeated breaking of the list into `BlankNullSequence`s, and the other with repeated `StringJoin`s (I'm actually not 100% sure that the last is avoidable, but it's certainly **possible** that `StringJoin`ing many strings at once is efficient, and that would explain why `StringJoin` has the `Flat` attribute).

I ended up doing what any functional programmer does when confronted with a problem they don't know how to solve: I used `Fold` to accumulate a linked list. This solution works, and seems like it could be efficient (in part by exploiting the `Flat`ness of `StringJoin`), but I haven't done actual performance testing. **EDIT**: Now I have a file to test with (linked below), and this solution runs in about 4 milliseconds. The naive solution takes about 25 milliseconds, and scales quadratically with length.

```
Pillsy`catenateContinuedLines[lines : {___String}] :=
 Module[{catenating},
  Attributes[catenating] = {HoldAllComplete};

  Flatten@Fold[
    Function[{acc, line},
     With[{
       (* This allows me to avoid repeating myself, but is a bit nuts. *)
       thunk =
        If[
         0 < StringLength@line && StringTake[line, -1] == "\\",
         With[{dropped = StringDrop[line, -1]},
          catenating@StringJoin[#, dropped] &],
         StringJoin[#, line] &]
       },
      acc /. {
        {init_, catenating[arg_]} :> {init, thunk[Unevaluated@arg]},
        _ -> {acc, thunk[""]}
        }]],
    {},
    lines]]
```

I checked briefly to see if there was an option for [`Import[file, {"Text", "Lines"}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Text.html) that would allow you to specify a line continuation character, but nothing jumped out at me. I have a solution, but it seems needlessly convoluted.

**EDIT** to add: I have a semi-realistic test file that's long enough that I can do some timing, but unfortunately can't make it public.

**EDIT** again to add: OK, I munged any identifying information in the file beyond all recognition, so if you want something for test timings, you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/3W4Xju7A).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### new one

This seems to be quite fast (*didn't test with yours*)

```
sc[{n_String}] := n;
sc[s_] := StringJoin[StringDrop[Most[s], -1]] <> Last[s]

sc /@ Split[testLines, StringMatchQ[#, "*\\"] &]
```

#### old one

```
StringJoin @@@ (
  Split[testLines, StringMatchQ[#, "*\\"] &] /. s : {Repeated[_String, {2, ∞}]} :> 
                                                     StringReplace[s, "\\" -> ""])
```

> ```
> {"foo", "barbazquux", "wongle\\ bongle", "wingle", "pringleprongle", "blort"}
> ```

Notice that this is `Split` not `SplitBy`. Important difference because from adjacent elements we only test former one.

Comment: That is considerably faster than my `Sow`/`Reap` solution (I have a test file I'm working on that I unfortunately can't make public); I like the trick of using a one-argument predicate with `Split`.

Comment: @Pillsy I have to thank you, this will help me with the task I was thinking about today :P

Comment: Using the munged test file above, your solution runs in about 0.5 milliseconds vs 1.5 milliseconds for my best attempt, `Sow`/`Reap`.

Comment: @Kuba: New one appears to get wrong result, e.g. I get "babaquux" instead of "barbazquux:...

Comment: @rasher o my, good catch. fixed.

Comment: This shows good performance, it's short, and it's straightforward. Accepted.

Comment: @Pillsy Isn't Jacob's solution better? It looks like it is. Feel free to accept his answer if so. Or maybe you can't assume that you can use "|"or something, it is only one disadvantage,

Comment: @Kuba That is, indeed, my concern. It's a little less robust.

Answer (score 5):

This solution requires that you know some character that does not occur in your string, in this example `"|"`

```
jacob[strList_] :=
 StringSplit[
  StringReplace[StringJoin[Riffle[strList, "|"]], "\\|" -> ""], "|"]
```

Maybe it will be fast because there are few function calls.

**Modified definitions of other answers**

```
sc[{n_String}] := n;
sc[s_] := StringJoin[StringDrop[Most[s], -1]] <> Last[s]

kuba[strList_] :=
 sc /@ Split[strList, StringMatchQ[#, "*\\"] &]

kubaOld[strList_] :=
 StringJoin @@@ (Split[strList, StringMatchQ[#, "*\\"] &] /. 
    s : {Repeated[_String, {2, \[Infinity]}]} :> 
     StringReplace[s, "\\" -> ""])

(*the solution by aky took more than 10 seconds*)
(*the solution in Pillsy's answer also took more than 10 seconds *)
```

**Timing comparison**

```
(jacobRes = jacob[words]) // Timing // First
(kubaRes = kuba[words]) // Timing // First
(kubaOldRes = kubaOld[words]) // Timing // First
(rmrfRes = joinWords[words]) // Timing // First
jacobRes === kubaRes === kubaOldRes == rmrfRes
```

gives

> 0.449849 
>   1.694213 
>   2.215579 
>   4.350092 
>   True

Comment: you can use `"LONGMARKER"`, highly unlikely to interfere :P

Comment: @Kuba haha yeah. I didn't realise the second argument of `StringSpit` could be a pattern as well. But yeah that would be slow :P

Comment: @Kuba thank you :). Yeah your old answer seems similar, I see you used a short version of "LONGMARKER" ;)

Comment: :p also, `Riffle` is my favorite function, I hate that you've used it with success not me ;P

Comment: @Kuba ahh, yes gotta love `Riffle` :D! I used to love it because it felt nice to do `Partition[Riffle[list1, list2],2]` (or something?), but I think it couldn't compete with `Transpose`/`Thread`.

Comment: `Riffle` is simple, `Thread` may be unintuitive.

Comment: @Kuba agreed! I will put that in my list of functions-by-complexity (I have lists of everything :P)

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to Kuba's solution, but uses the listability of  `ToCharacterCode`/`FromCharacterCode` instead of string patterns. Sometimes, this can be a bit faster than string manipulations:

```
joinWords[list_] := Join @@@ (Split[ToCharacterCode@list, Last[#] == 92 &] /. 
    {h__, 92} :> {h}) // FromCharacterCode

joinWords@Pillsy`testLines   
(* {"foo", "barbazquux", "wongle\\ bongle", "wingle", "pringleprongle", "blort"} *)
```

Comment: This one is considerably slower than Kuba's solution; 2.5 ms vs 0.5 ms.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative solution, that seems faster, but isn't really that much less horrible, uses `Sow`/`Reap` and increments a counter to use as a tag:

```
Pillsy`reapCatenateContinuedLines[lines : {___String}] :=
 Module[{counter = 0},
  StringJoin @@@ Last@Reap[
     Scan[
      If[StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "\\"],
        Sow[StringDrop[#, -1], counter],
        Sow[#, counter++]] &,
      lines]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't really evaluated this in terms of speed, but throwing it into the mix anyway:

```
f[] := Sequence[]
f[first_String, rest___String] := 
 If[StringTake[first, -1] == "\\", 
  f[StringDrop[first, -1] <> First@{rest}, 
   Sequence @@ Rest@{rest}], {first, f[rest]}]

Flatten[f @@ Pillsy`testLines]
(* {"foo", "barbazquux", "wongle\\ bongle", "wingle", "pringleprongle", "blort"} *)
```

Comment: This is going to have performance problems similar to the ones with ``Pillsy`naiveCatenateContinuedLines`; when I tried it with twice as many lines of input, it took about 4 times as long. The common functional programming idiom of recursively breaking a list into a head and a tail doesn't really work with Mathematica's pattern matching.

Comment: I would've expected that - because of the (head: tail) pattern match - this would be faster, at least compared to matching in the middle of a list, as you do in your naiveCatenateContinuedLines. I tried my function on a list 10 times the size of your test lines (basically generated by doing `Flatten[ConstantArray[Pillsy`testLines, 10]]` ) and `Timing` showed that it was 10 times slower compared to the original. A 100 times larger list came out to be 200-300 times slower compared to the original. (But yeah, doesn't hold a candle to Kuba's solution.)